# Why im not getting all the values from the select element?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I ran into a little problem, when i submit the form through JS i would like to get all of the values from the select element... I mean like for every user the value of the select element.

```
<?php foreach($users as $user) : ?>
  <div>
      <p><?php echo $user['user_first'].' '.$user['user_last']; ?></p>
          <form action="" method="post">
          <select name="user-state">
            <option value="Je na hodine">Je na hodine</option>
            <option value="Chýba">Chýba</option>
            <option value="Meškanie">Meškanie</option>
        </select>
        <input type="input" name="user" value="">
        </form>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('saveBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){
document.getElementById('dochadzka-form').submit();  });
```

Comment: When an HTML form is submitted, the variables being sent are created by taking the names and values of every input (textarea, select, etc.) element. You use the same name many times. Try `<select name="user-state[]">` to get an array on server side.

Comment: Every user represents an individual form tag on your html. You have to put all values you want to process in one form tag.

Comment: If you want to submit data from multiple forms, make sure to use individual names for the different select fields. Otherwise, you will have problems to connect the list of users to a second list of states

Comment: it returned/gave me an array but with only the first value... :/, what do you mean by that? @nologin

Comment: As Nico said, use names to differ between the users. I expected only one form to be processed.

Comment: Your JS code references items which are not in your HMTL.

Comment: You are not assining an ID to your forms. Without it you can't use getElementById.

Comment: i actually have it in my code but i dont know why it is here :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the data on a single submit you need to wrap all inputs inside a single form. To get the data as an array in PHP after submitting you should format the `name` attribute like `name="user-state[]"`.

Something like this should do the trick (untested):

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <?php foreach($users as $user) : ?>
    <fieldset>
      <legend><?php echo $user['user_first'].' '.$user['user_last'] ?></legend>
      <input name="user[]" value="<?php echo $user['id'] ?>" type="hidden">
      <select name="user-state[]">
        <option value="Je na hodine">Je na hodine</option>
        <option value="Chýba">Chýba</option>
        <option value="Meškanie">Meškanie</option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

An example to illustrate how this works:

```js
// This is only needed to show the form data in this example.
// If you only need the data in PHP you don't need any JavaScript.
var form = document.getElementById("dochadzka-form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  var data = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form)).toString();
  console.log(data);
  
  event.preventDefault(event);
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="dochadzka-form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>User 1</legend>
    <input name="user[]" value="1" type="hidden">
    <select name="user-state[]">
      <option value="Je na hodine">Je na hodine</option>
      <option value="Chýba">Chýba</option>
      <option value="Meškanie">Meškanie</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  
  <fieldset>
    <legend>User 2</legend>
    <input name="user[]" value="2" type="hidden">
    <select name="user-state[]">
      <option value="Je na hodine">Je na hodine</option>
      <option value="Chýba">Chýba</option>
      <option value="Meškanie">Meškanie</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button> to show the form data
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php $i = 0; foreach($users as $user) : ?>
  <div>
      <p><?php echo $user['user_first'].' '.$user['user_last']; ?></p>
          <select name="user-state<?= $i?>">
            <option value="Je na hodine">Je na hodine</option>
            <option value="Chýba">Chýba</option>
            <option value="Meškanie">Meškanie</option>
        </select>
        <input type="input" name="user<?= $i?>" value="">
    </div>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
</form>
```